# Cordova InAppBrowser and FaceBook App Event Logger

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to implement FB's AppEventLogger in an APP in order to track user behavior and purchases.
The "APP" is hybrid - it is cordova based. It is loaded from InAppBrowser and is actually a javascript/PHP website. 
I am using the Javascript API for the AppEventLogger like so:

```
var $fCity = $('#fromCity').val();
var $tCity = $('#toCity').val();
var params = { };
params[FB.AppEvents.ParameterNames.CONTENT_TYPE] = $fCity + ' - ' + $tCity;
FB.AppEvents.logEvent(
    FB.AppEvents.EventNames.SEARCHED,
    null, 
    params
);
```

Which sends the following request to facebook:

[image: request made from the app inside the inappbrowser]

When this request is sent from the app to facebook, nothing happens. The event is not logged.
However, when the same link/request is opened/made from a regular browser, even by just visiting the InAppBrowser source page trough the browser, the event is logged.
Also, I have the Facebook SDK installed as a Cordova plugin and send events via the plugin (as an app - when it starts and ends) - then it also works. But since the app is inside the inappbrowser, I can not use that plugin for the other pages.

I have checked the whitelist plugin and connections are allowed to facebook.com. You can even see that we get a 200 response and the gif headers from Facebook's server.

Why does Facebook's AppEventBrowser not log events sent from the InAppBrowser plugin?

Comment: How did you config your whitelist plugin and access allowed? Try to allow everything for the test `<access origin="*" />`. It is possible to redirect your inAppBroweser window to graph subdomain, different page or protocol  which is not allowed on your side.

Comment: @XristoEftimov I have installed cordova-plugin-whitelist and configured the following in the html file: <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://connect.facebook.net"/> 
I can also open any external website inside the InAppBrowser without any issues.

Comment: Can you open the console and to track the packages that you send ?

Comment: @XristoEftimov yes I can. The screenshot is from the console with the request to FB's event logger.

Comment: Do you have an JavaScript errors ?

Comment: @DreamWave Did you check out this link - https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin#events It has more info on how to log events in mobile app

Comment: @XristoEftimov there are no JavaScript errors - the same code, If opened from a browser works.

Comment: @Gandhi that is a reference to the cordova plugin's documentation. I am trying to log events inside InAppBrowser

Comment: @dreamwave I do agree.. Wondering why cant you use the plugin to make use of Facebook integration and logging

Comment: @Gandhi because the plugin can not be triggered from inside of InAppBrowser

Comment: @Dreamwave I feel you can make use of the event listeners in inappbrowser to execute the required callback... Check out this link - https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/README.md#inappbrowseraddeventlistener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a way to get around the limitation. In the end I used the Cordova plugin for facebook's SDK to do what I want to.

Comment: What was the name of the plugin ? Was it `ordova-plugin-facebook4` ?

Answer (score -1):

Few things to check 
 1. First load the debug version of JS SDK 
(js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/debug.js";)
and see the logs.

 2. inAppBrowser can't access Cordova APIs so just in case any part of your code/library is trying to access a Cordova API so that may generate an issue, and maybe a request argument is missing which Facebook event requires by default to log (e.g. it logs android version etc.). You can compare the arguments with a successful request.
For hybrid apps the recommended way by Facebook is to use the event API
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/app-event-api/v2.8

> For other platforms that utilize web-view within a native app, one option would be to utilize the App Events API to pass events from your server to the Facebook servers.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/faq

Comment: I am checking in the logs and I do not get any event published to FB, when sent from the JavaScript API.

I know InAppBrowser can't access cordova APIs, which is what was discussed in the comments on the question. There are no missing arguments, because, as I said, the same page, when opened from a browser, instead of with InAppBrowser works correctly. As I said, THE SAME REQUEST works from a browser - I have compared parameters and headers between the working and non-working request.
I am using the App Event Api - you can see that from the code "FB.AppEvents.logEvent .."

Comment: I wish you would have checked the links before commenting and down voting. What you are using is FB JS SDK, not event API.

Comment: The second idea was to check and compare, not a solution, more of debugging.